# How do i calculate the time period in days for which the customer was active using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

[image: dataset]

How do i calculate the time period in days for which the customer was active using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```